# How to parse jsonlines file using pandas

Tags: python, json, jsonlines

I am new to python and trying to parse data from a file that contains millions of lines. Tried to go old school to parse it using excel but it fails. How can I parse the information efficiently and export them into an excel file so that it is easier for other people to read?

I tried using this code provided by someone else but no luck so far

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

def clean_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as inputfile:
        for row in inputfile:
            if re.match("\[", row) is None:
                yield row

with open(clean_file,  'w') as outputfile:
    for row in clean_data(filename):
        outputfile.write(row)
```

```py
NameError: name 'clean_file' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `clean_file` is not defined, which is probably a problem from copy/pasteing code.

Did you mean to write to a file called "clean_file"? In which case you need to wrap it in quotes: `with open("clean_file",  'w')`

If you want to work with json I sugget looking into the [json package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) which has lots of tools for loading and parsing json. Otherwise, if the json is flat, you can just use the inbuilt pandas function [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Comment: yes I need to define `clean_file` and I added `max_records = 1e5` at the end and it works. thanks a bunch for the help to a newbie!